# How to get first 9 digits of a column in openquery?

Tags: sql, ssms, openquery

I am using SSMS to pull some data from oracle via openquery and only need the first 9 digits of a number out of a column.

I have tried using "left(column1, 9)" and it returns "LEFT:invalid identifier"

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(servername,'
    SELECT left(sv.column2, 9) AS new_number
    FROM server.servername sv
')
```

column2 = 0987654321
new_number = 098765432

Answer (score 1):

You miss the "Select"
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([SERVER\INSTANCE],' select left(sv.column, 9) AS new_number FROM BD.dbo.Table sv')

Good Code.

Comment: Select was in my code. I'm not sure how it didn't end up in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you would use `substring()`, so something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(sv.column2, 1, 9) AS new_number
FROM server.servername sv
```

Comment: I am not using oracle, I am using openquery from SSMS.

Comment: @jrussin . . . You are querying a remote Oracle server, so your SQL should be compatible with Oracle.